# Why do I get "undefined method" in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a trouble with the routes in Ruby on Rails 4, and receiving this error:

```
undefined method `routes_path'
```

My view is:

```
<h1>Load data</h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for @route, :html => { :multipart => true } do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'current_user', @current_user %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file %>
        <%= submit_tag "Import", style: 'margin-top: -10px', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

My controller is:

```
def new
    @route = current_user.build_route
end

def create
     nil_flag = Route.import(params[:file], current_user)
    if nil_flag == 1
      flash[:success] = "Data created."
      redirect_to route_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error"
      redirect_to load_data_path
    end
end
```

My model is:

```
def self.import(file, current_user)
   @user = current_user
   @route = @user.build_route
   @nil_flag = 0

   File.open(file.path, 'r') do |f|
   .
   .
   .
    #etc
end
```

The routes are:

```
match '/load_data', to: 'routes#new', via: 'get'
```

My views, controller and model are named "Route".

Is there a problem with the route in the view or something else?

Comment: Is that your only route? I would expect something like this as well: `match '/load_data', to: 'routes#create', via: 'post', as: 'routes'`--I'm guessing here based on what your `form_for` tag seems to be expecting (`routes_path`).

Comment: there is other routes, but not involved to the 'routes' controller, actually that is my only route to that controller
BTW if i put the as: 'routes' it shows a undefined method `load_data_path'error

Comment: Ok. I would expect you to have two routes (at least)--a 'get' route pointing to `RoutesController::new` that returns your page with a form with empty fields, and a 'post' route pointing to `RoutesController::create` that receives the contents of the completed form. (This may be GET /load_data and POST /load_data, even though the naming of the URL is a bit unintuitive.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to [specify a name for your route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) so Rails will create the `_path` helper:

```
match '/load_data', to: 'routes#new', via: 'get', as: :routes
```

This creates a `routes_path` helper that returns `/load_data`.

It's usually easier to use [resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

```
resources :routes, path: '/load_data'
```

The above line will create the following routes:

```
HTTP Verb  Path                 Action   Named Helper
GET        /load_data           index    routes_path
GET        /load_data/new       new      new_routes_path
POST       /load_data           create   routes_path
GET        /load_data/:id       show     route_path(:id)
GET        /load_data/:id/edit  edit     edit_route_path(:id)
PATCH/PUT  /load_data/:id       update   route_path(:id)
DELETE     /load_data/:id       destroy  route_path(:id)
```

You can run `rake routes` in your terminal to get a list of the available routes.